# Is there a good example of computing a sequence that illustrates the Halting Problem?

Tags: halting-problem

I know that Busy Beaver problem can be used to illustrate the Halting Problem and it's probably the canonical problem used when talking about the Halting Problme . But long time ago I came across some a computation of a sequence from a starting value, that was used to illustrate the problem (I thought the source was Understanding Computation by Tom Stuart, but it isn't) but I can't find the source material.

The mathematical sequence in particular had the following characteristics

- The values were integers
- The was some end condition (Something like if the last value was 1 or 0 the sequence ends)
- The operations were simple (I believe they were just arithmetic, bitwise ops, modulo, sqrt,power, etc.)
- Depending on the initial value it could come to an end value (so in some cases the program calculating the sequence will actually halt / terminate)
- Some initial values led to cycles of repeating values. That was a clear indicative that the program will never halt.
- The sequence numbers were going up and down, so you couldn't tell if it was converging.
- Some initial values led to short sequences (that were printed in the book / article)
- Some initial values led to long sequences that will take maybe hours to compute,
- The were some initial values that lead to sequence that nobody knows if they will ever complete (thus the halting problem reference). The source material mentioned that X number of the sequence had been calculated for initial value Y, so that makes me believe that is **well-known mathematical sequence**.

At the time I found that this sequence was very understandable, since it was clear by inspecting the code that you couldn't tell if it will ever finish, that everything depended on the initial value and even knowing the initial value you couldn't reason if the termination condition will ever be met.

I remember that was easier than the Busy Beaver implementation since it was just a while loop until the sequence termination condition was met.

Does this description fits any well known mathematical sequence?

Comment: Are you talking about the Collatz conjecture ? (Even $n\to\frac n2$, odd $n\to3n+1$.)

Comment: Well, it could be, but I kind of remember that there was some initial values that lead to infinite loops (repeating number) , so that would have "disproved" the Collatz conjecture. I could be misremembering the example, though.

Comment: The Collatz conjecture is still open.

Comment: Yes, I undestand. That why I think maybe the example I saw was not the Collatz sequence since there was at least one example  in the book/article (if my memory does not fail me) where the sequence will never end since the numbers where repeating. Anyway, Collazt it a good example

Comment: also, I see that the collatz sequences for all  starting values< 1000000 are relatively short (524 steps) so that doesn't match with my recollection of the sequence in question, it there were starting values that produce short sequences,  starting values that produced long sequences, some that produced infinite sequences, and some that produced really long sequences that it's was discussed if they will ever converge or not.

Comment: @RubenLaguna Case 1) your sequence is among [the list of undecidable problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems). Case 2) If not, you may add it to that list when you come across it again.